# How to play() a <video> injected with load() from JQuery using video.js?

Tags: jquery, ajax, video.js

you have a nice time.

I need help with this issue:
I'm injecting a  tag using video.js and the load() function from JQuery. But when I executed:

```
$('#video-hero')[0].player.play();
```

I get this error on console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined
```

I've into my code this:

```
$('.play').on('click',function(){
  $('#headerVideo').modal('show');});


$('#headerVideo').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
var videoSpace = $('#headerVideo .modal-dialog-video .row .col-md-12');
videoSpace.load('/assets/incl/video-header.html', function(){
  $('#video-hero')[0].player.play();
});})
```

Can someone help me?

Thank you:

Comment: have you tried `$('#video-hero')[0].play();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using video.js, you should use its API to play the video. The original `video` element will have been replaced with the video.js player `div` which may or may not contain a `video`, depending on what tech is used.

From your snippet I can't see exactly what you've got, but this would work if you had `<video id="video-hero" ...` that has since been initialised as a video.js player.

```
videojs('video-hero').play();
```

Comment: works perfectly like this. Thank you so much.
When I'm enabled to vote I'll do it.